# Use apply function in all columns at once in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda database with several columns, I want to make two types of filters based on a list:

1 - Filter rows that contain at least one item in the list, regardless of the column

2 - Filter rows that contain all items in the row. For example, column 1 might contain one element, and column 2 might contain another element

An example of the database I have

`df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ["Bonjour (coouse); je teste", "La nuit (horrible)", "La troisième voie"], 'B' : ["La première voie", "Bonjour (coouse); ou pas", "La nuit (horrible)"]}) df`

I've tried this filter, it only works per column, whereas I want to apply on all columns. It doesn't matter what the column is, if a row contains that value, then I display it.

`df.loc[df['A'].apply(lambda x: any([k in x for k in ["Bonjour (coouse)", "La troisième voie"]]))]`

The second solution I'd like to have is the & condition: all the values in the list must be contained in one of the columns. For example, the first value might be in column 1 and the second value in the list might be in column 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to match substrings, I would use a regex approach.

###### Filter rows that contain at least one item in the list, regardless of the column

Here we craft a regex, extract the substrings and keep the rows with at least a non-NA value

```
import re

target = ["Bonjour (coouse)", "La troisième voie"]

pattern = '(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, target))
# '(Bonjour\\ \\(coouse\\)|La\\ troisième\\ voie)'

out = df[df.apply(lambda s: s.str.extract(pattern, expand=False))
           .notna().any(axis=1)]
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/doGR0L/1)

###### Filter rows that contain all items in the row

We can craft the same regex, but instead count the number of different values that we have extracted, to have all it should match the length of the list:

```
import re

target = ["Bonjour (coouse)", "La troisième voie"]

pattern = '(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, target))
# '(Bonjour\\ \\(coouse\\)|La\\ troisième\\ voie)'

out = df[df.apply(lambda s: s.str.extract(pattern, expand=False))
           .nunique(axis=1).eq(len(target))]
```

Alternatively, for the last step, using `set` operations (less efficient):

```
out = df[df.apply(lambda s: s.str.extract(pattern, expand=False))
           .agg(set, axis=1).eq(set(target))]
```

###### intermediate

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.str.extract(pattern, expand=False))

                   A                 B
0   Bonjour (coouse)               NaN
1                NaN  Bonjour (coouse)
2  La troisième voie               NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! When I try on my whole data I have this error Error on line 1444 AttributeError Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: Make sure you have strings: `df.astype(str).apply(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Mask the values which are not present in the list then count the unique values along the columns axis. Then use this `count` to filter the rows

```
lst = ["Bonjour (coouse)", "La troisième voie"]
count = df.where(df.isin(lst)).nunique(axis=1)
```

---

```
# Contains at least one item
df[count >= 1]

#                    A                   B
# 2  La troisième voie  La nuit (horrible)

# Contains all items
df[count == len(lst)]

# Empty DataFrame
# Columns: [A, B]
# Index: []
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the requirements correctly, you should be able to use a similar method to add an additional filter to your df.

```
df.loc[(df['A'].apply(lambda x: any([k in x for k in ["Bonjour (coouse)", "La troisième voie"]]))) | (df.apply(lambda x: all([k in x for k in ["Bonjour (coouse)", "La troisième voie"]]),axis=1))]
```

In this code snippet, it simply uses the pipe operator `|` to add another filter to your df. Now it would return any row where `["Bonjour (coouse)", "La troisième voie"]` are present in column 'A' (as you had already done). This will also return any rows that contain all of the values in `["Bonjour (coouse)", "La troisième voie"]`. Currently no rows in your df meet this requirement, however if your df added one extra row:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Bonjour (coouse); je teste | La troisième voie |

This would also be returned by the filters.